# Rotating a water wheel

Tags: animation

I have this problem:

I'm trying to make a water wheel rotation but i can't render it smoothly,

I've tried rotating it by 45/90/180° and it always have thise freeze from last frame to the first frame. Ending at the last-1 frame doesn't help much. And rotating by 360° doesn't help either cause it just doesn't turn, stays at the same position. I've tried different end frames like 30 or 60 frames for 30-60fps but it doesn't change much either.

Here's a gif of what it looks like when it turn 45° in 30frames

[image]

The end of the gif is just a buggy gid it doesn't do that in blender.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When only you animate frame 1 to 60, it means that it will not start at frame 1 with full speed and it will not end at frame 60 with full speed, butthe motion will get faster in the beginning and slower in the end. Go to Graph Editor and look how the rotation-curve is getting steeper.

To counter that you can start the animation earlier and end later. Or you manipulate the development of the roation in den Graph Editor, making it a constant movement.

[image]

Comment: Oh woa thanks, I followed your graph and it worked.